# how can i delete the records from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created one link on different page (Delete). After that, I wrote following code to execute the query, but somehow it's showing the 'success' message, but it's not deleting particular record from database... Any suggestions?

```
<?php
        include_once('data_conn.php');
        $id=$_GET['id'];
             $sql = "DELETE FROM driver_info where id=$id";
                  echo $sql;
                    if(!$sql ) {
                                  echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("something went Wrong...:(((("); location.href="user-profile.php"';
            echo '</script>';
           }
                    else{
                       echstrong texto '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("successfully Deleted!!!"); location.href="user-profile.php"';
            echo '</script>';
            mysql_close();
                    }
?>
```

Comment: You aren't executing your query

Comment: This code is open to SQL injections.

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never executing the query you are just storing the query string in 
$sql. You should first execute the query with

mysqli_query($sql);

Comment: Thanks!.... it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

> somehow it showing 'success' message but its not deleting

Because you are only echoing the query. Stop using `mysql_*`, instead do it with mysqli, and use `mysqli_query`.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php